# Concatenate row items in quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have

```
Bill Number Bill Amount
String      Int

BillNo1
BillNo2
BillNo3
```

How can concatenate the Bill Numbers?

I want to get :

`BillNo1+BillNo2+BillNo3` or `BillNo1,BillNo2,BillNo3`

Have checked the quicksight documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/concat-function.html but not sure if this can be used here